How can I fix TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable error? I have set it in edit system environment variables and it still does not work
I am trying to learn how to use tesseract OCR and I am receiving this error: pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
The code I am trying to run is as follows:
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import cv2



# Read the image
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/.../portfolio/OCR/practicematerials/OCR with Python/Images/page-book.jpg")

#config tesseract
configTesseract = '--tessdata-dir tessdata --psm 6'
#change the color format to be tesseract format
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#show the image
#cv2.imshow('window', rgb)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(rgb, lang='eng', config=configTesseract)
print(text)

# closing all open windows 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 


 dir env: | Where-Object -Property Name -like "tessdata*"
returns:
TESSDATA_PREFIX                C:\Users\...\portfolio\OCR\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata 
I have also tried:
TESSDATA_PREFIX                C:\Users...\portfolio\OCR\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata
TESSDATA_PREFIX                C:\Users...\portfolio\OCR\Tesseract-OCR\
Between each of these attempts I have rebooted my computer. I am on Windows 11, using python 3.12, and tesseract v5.3.3.20231005
I do not get this error without configTesseract = '--tessdata-dir tessdata --psm 6' and with text = pytesseract.image_to_string(rgb)
